# Is there an addon for touch input?

Tags: add-on

My math teacher is interested in using Blender in class to help with visual learning. Is there an extension out there that makes Blender usable with only a touchscreen?

We have a Promethean in class, so if there's an addon for that, let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Everything in 2.8 seems to be somewhere on a menu/panel/control whereas in 2.79 somethings were completely hidden unless you had the shortcut. I think you would need to try it see where you get stuck.